# How do I go through individual elements in a list in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, rules

I am writing a Lite version of Eliza https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA in Prolog. These are the statements I want to give and the responses I want to receive (the statements are given in list form):

Ready> [i,feel,fine]
Eliza: why do you feel fine
Ready> [you,are,a,computer]
Eliza: i am not a computer
Ready> [do,you,speak,portuguese]
Eliza: no, i speak russian

I am feeding in a list of rules that change the statement words to response words like this:

```
change(X,Y):- X = 'you', Y = 'i'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'i', Y = 'why do you'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'are', Y = 'am not'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'do', Y = 'no'.
change(X,Y):- X = 'portuguese', Y = 'russian'.
```

and my infinite interactive loop for the prompt and response looks like this:

```
eliza:-
    nl,
    write("Ready> "),
    read(X),
    answer(X,Y),
    write('Eliza: '),
    write(Y),
    nl,
    eliza.
```

My question lies with the `answer(X,Y)` part of the loop. If `read(X)` takes the list of words like [i,feel,fine], then how do I make a rule `answer(X,Y)` that will take each element of the list in order and call the corresponding `change(X,Y)` rule to change the word and insert it back into the result Y? Do I have to use a form of recursion and create another rule?

Comment: You probably should not use `(is)/2` but `(=)/2`.

Comment: Read the Prolog documentation for `is/2`. It is intended for unifying the first argument with the evaluated arithmetic expression of the second argument. Also, your predicate `Eliza` has an invalid name since it is capitalized. Predicates must start with a lower case letter.

Comment: The idea of creating a new list from an old one by transforming each element in turn is a very common operation in Prolog. It's so common, there's a predicate you can use to do this for you: `maplist`. You should look it up and try it. It's just a pattern: `answer([In|Ins], [Out|Outs]) :- <convert In to Out>, answer(Ins, Outs).` and then you need an appropriate base case.